# How to open and replace image texture via command line

Tags: texturing, scripting, command-line

This is how i could replace the `Base Color` if it was just a default color option : `bpy.data.materials["Material"].node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"].inputs[0].default_value = (0, 0.1 ,0 , 1)`

But I am wondering how i could do the same if I was replacing an `Image Texture` option instead.

Posting image of GUI for reference. (basically wanna simulate selecting an image in Python script)

[image]

[image]

Comment: if you just wanna exchange/replace (as your title says) "another" image you can use this: bpy.data.images['Feb-9_color.png'].filepath = ... new image....

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete setup for materials you can use. If you get stuck at any point please let me know. Hope it helps

```
import bpy

cube = bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name='Material')
mat.use_nodes = True
bpy.context.object.active_material = mat

nodes = mat.node_tree.nodes
links = mat.node_tree.links
nodes.clear()

principle = nodes.new('ShaderNodeBsdfPrincipled')
principle.location = 200, 0


output = nodes.new('ShaderNodeOutputMaterial')
output.location = 600, 0

image = nodes.new('ShaderNodeTexImage')
image.location = -200, 0 
#Assign Image
image.image = bpy.data.images['YOUR IMAGE NAME HERE']

links.new(image.outputs[0], principle.inputs[0])

links.new(principle.outputs[0], output.inputs[0])
```